# What is the meaning of "Class<>" in C++?

Tags: c++, syntax

I'm not new to C++ but I haven't coded much using it either. I have recently come across code that has "<>" in the variable declaration. Here is how it looks

```
MyClass<> *instancePtr;
```

I'm sure it has something to do with templates, but I can't really find anything online. Can anyone help me out with this? What does the code mean?

Any help is appreciated,
Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It means that `MyClass` is a template and that `MyClass` template declaration supplies default arguments for all template parameters.

For example, if the template is declared as follows

```
template <typename T = int, typename U = double, int N = 5> class MyClass {
  ...
};
```

then

```
MyClass<> *instancePtr;
```

is equivalent to

```
MyClass<int, double, 5> *instancePtr;
```

Note that when you are referring to a template class, the `<>` is always required, even if there's nothing between the `<>`. You cannot just say

```
MyClass *instancePtr;
```

even if all template parameters have default arguments. (Some older compilers supported this incorrect usage.)

Comment: **or** `MyClass` has variadic template arguments and no arguments are passed